# The Gell-Mann and Low theorem and the expansion of the Green function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, greens-functions

If we have a system with Hamiltonian $H = H_{0} + V$, with $| \Phi_{0} \rangle$ being the ground state of the system without the interaction, the Gell-Mann and Low theorem say that the quantite

$$ |\xi \rangle \equiv \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}  \frac{U_{\varepsilon}(0, - \infty) |\Phi_{0} \rangle}{\langle \Phi_{0} | U_{\varepsilon}(0, - \infty) |\Phi_{0} \rangle}$$

is a eigenstate of the exact hamiltonian $H$ of the system, but even if $| \Phi_{0} \rangle$ is the ground state of the non-interacting system, $| \xi \rangle$ is not necessarily the ground state of the interacting system, right? The book "Quantum theory of Many Particle Systems", of Fetter and Walecka say it. However, the mostly text books use the theorem as if $| \xi \rangle$ was the ground state of $H$. The fetter and Walecka themselves do this when they expand the Green function. They proof the relation

$$\langle \Psi_{0} | O(t) | \Psi_{0} \rangle = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^{n}}{n!}\int dt_{1} \cdots \int dt_{n} e^{\varepsilon(|t_{1}| + ... + |t_{n}|)} \frac{\langle \Phi_{0} |T[V(t_{1}) \cdots V(t_{n})O(t)]|\Phi_{0} \rangle}{\langle \Phi_{0} | U_{\varepsilon}(\infty, - \infty)|\Phi_{0} \rangle} $$

where $\Psi_{0}$ is the ground state simply taking $$|\Psi_{0} \rangle = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}  U_{\varepsilon}(0, - \infty) |\Phi_{0} \rangle/\langle \Phi_{0} | U_{\varepsilon}(0, - \infty) |\Phi_{0} \rangle.$$ So, I am confused, can I apply the theorem for any eigenstate of $H$?

Comment: Are they not mentioning the caveat that as the interactions are adiabatically turned on, the system should not encounter level crossings?

Comment: They don't say it, but it's possible. So, can I always assume it?

Comment: I think this is implicitly assumed almost everywhere. There might be subtleties which i might not be aware of.